# How much does the radioactive core of a nuclear bomb shrink due to compression by conventional explosives before it goes critical?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, density, volume

I saw a claim online that the conventional explosions used to detonate a nuclear bomb "significantly" compress the radioactive core, but I can't find any numbers indicating by how much the core actually shrinks in radius before going critical. I'm sure that it takes an enormous amount of pressure to physically reduce the volume of a solid uranium or plutonium sphere, so I wouldn't expect the total volume to decrease by very much, despite this claim. Are there numbers on this?

Comment: B. Cameron Reed has a long list of articles in the American Journal of Physics on the physics behind the Manhattan project. In particular American Journal of Physics 88, 565 (2020); doi: 10.1119/10.0001206 is on the Serber plot. Note that the pressure to get 1-10% efficiency is on the order of 10$^{11}$ to 10$^{12}$ atmospheres. Do you consider this an 'enormous amount of pressure'? And what is a large decrease in volume to you?

Comment: Or, if you prefer, https://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Library/Implsion.html says "The convergent shock wave of an implosion can compress solid uranium or plutonium by a factor of 2 to 3."

Comment: @JonCuster, I have seen similar numbers before, but it was never clear to me whether they were talking about the volume of the core, the radius of the core, or whether they actually were talking about the _multiplication factor_ for prompt neutrons. Also, I distrust that they said, "compress _solid_ uranium..." By the time it is compressed by the detonation wave, it no longer is a "solid."

Comment: @SolomonSlow - indeed it is no longer a solid, but the compression of 2-3x is still correct.

Comment: For solid data, something like https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJs9PLj8TtAhWNVc0KHfjLDtsQFjAEegQIDBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1502.00497&usg=AOvVaw0CrCX9wIJx6RKzSNfazvRS might be appropriate.

Comment: "compress solid uranium..." Aren't these implosion cores made of Pu/Ga alloy, not U?

Comment: @Gert - a few atomic percent Ga is added to stabilize the preferred phase across a wide temperature range. It is not a separate phase, Ga is a solute in the Pu.

Comment: @JonCuster Sure.  I didn't say otherwise. But amirte saying 'Fat Man' type bombs are always $\text{Pu}^{239}$ (+ small amount of $\text{Ga}$) based? Never $\text{U}$?

Comment: @Gert, Not sure what you mean by "fat man type," but if you mean an implosion-type "atom bomb" or "h-bomb" trigger, then that describes every nuclear weapon ever built except one. There have been a number of different designs, all based on the same idea, that have been built and tested over the years. Some of them used a plutonium core, others used an HEU core. That is, in fact, the entire reason for enriching uranium beyond the percentage that is needed by power reactors.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thank you Solomon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively simple ["Point kinetic model of the early phase
of a spherically symmetric nuclear explosion"](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1606.01670) gives a volume compression factor $(R_\mathrm{initial}/R_\mathrm{minimum})^3$ of about $2.5$ for the Trinity Explosion, consistent with the factor of "2-3" [commonly reported](https://www.google.com/search?&q=atomic+bomb+compress+%222+to+3%22).

Answer (score 2):

Flash photos of test implosions of the "Trinity"-type (Fat Man) core as shown in the book "How To Photograph An Atomic Bomb" indicate that the diameter of the core is reduced by at least half and possibly more at the peak squeeze point.

Comment: Thanks, the Rapatronic photos are incredible. But I don't see how any conclusion could possibly be drawn about the minimum compressed diameter of the core from these photos. They are not taken close enough to the time of the explosion, and do not have sufficient resolution or the dynamic range to see the actual core.